# Blender Operation Success or Failure Feedback?

Tags: command-line, operator

Sometimes when I try to apply an operation in Blender (e.g. Mesh > Faces > Tris to Quads) nothing seems to happen (similar to [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?82950-Why-doesn-t-quot-Convert-Triangle-to-Quads-quot-work)). I wonder whether I selected the correct operation, or what else I might be doing incorrectly.

Is there a way to see any feedback on the success or failure of an operation? I'm used to software (such as Rhino), that puts useful messages in the command line after each operation like "3 meshes joined" or error messages explaining why the operation failed.

Comment: For Tris to Quads specifically, it may not convert all tris to quads for various reasons, e.g. it might cause non-flat faces. Try adjusting the angles (Max Face Angle and Max Shape Angle) and see if that helps. If you have similar problems with other tools, adding examples would make it easier to understand why it happens.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley, thanks for the tip. I'll put other problems in separate questions. I'm _really interested_ in finding out whether I can get instantaneous success/failure feedback from Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### F6 (operator properties)

Operators may still be active, if you press F6 after noticing a seemingly 'no-op' operator you can get a chance to tweak parameters.

[image]

#### Info Panel (Operator reporting)

As a rule you will get some kind of confirmation that an operator has completed, you could drop down the Info panel to see any output printed by the operator.

[image]

#### Terminal / Console

For more verbose messages sometimes operators print to the Command window, on windows this can be opened while Blender is running ( *Window > Toggle System Console*). On *osx* or *linux* Blender needs to be started from a terminal to get the print-outs.

**Windows users be warned**
Don't close the Console window manually using the X, that will close Blender. To close the System Console, click the menu item at *Window > Toggle System Console* again -- that will toggle the console off.

Comment: Thanks zeffii, that is _exactly_ what I wanted! By the way, what software did you use to create that GIF? I think the use of a GIF to demonstrate how to open the Info Panel was _very appropriate_.

Comment: @MechtEngineer I used [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) for windows - that's the original site (disclaimer, this is not an endorsement...etc).